# Numeric Keyboard with Kivy / KivyMD for MDTextField

Tags: python, keyboard, kivy, kivymd, numeric-keypad

How to make the Text Fields use the numeric android keyboard instead of the normal keyboard with all the letters?
NOTE: I'm using KivyMD MDTextFields
So when I click to write in the text fields a keyboard like this appears instead:

[Like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8SAW.jpg)

Comment: It seems the numeric keyboard from android is able to be used in kivy but I will review more information about it, right now this link may help https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/7545

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the py file I created my own class for custom keyboard:

```
class CustomTextField(MDTextField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.input_type = "number"
        self.input_type = "tel"
        self.input_filter = 'float'
        self.multiline = False
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

And then in the buildozer.spec file I changed the line:

```
p4a.branch = master
```

to:

```
p4a.branch = develop
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, I found an article where it said to use the `input_type: 'number'` inside your MDTextField that opens the android numeric keypad! I'm compiling my code again to see if it checks. Ex.:

```
MDTextField:
            id: quantidade
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            input_type: 'number'
            hint_text: "Qtd."
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
            helper_text: 'Insira uma quantidade (Apenas Números, "," e ".")'
```